# How do I make my declaration files for the typescript library available for install at @types/mylibrary

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-declaration

I have created my Library and published it to npm and works fine. The problem is I can't get the intellisence on my editor(vs code). Putting the declarations files manually on node_modules/@types
works perfectly. I want my types to be available for download on npm using **npm i @types/mylibrary**.

On my search I came accross this https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped which requires pulling all the available types and sending a PR for the new Type.

Is there any simple way of archiving the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's necessary.

Does your current `ts.config` already produce types?

Just add `types` to your `package.config`, for instance like so:

```
{
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    ...
}
```

(assuming outDir is `/dist/`)

Comment: Can you see the `d.ts` file in `node_modules` in the project where this library is a dependency?

Comment: Yes it is there [here is the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/qAiKx5L)

Comment: and if you write `import * as x from '<your-lib>';`, and then type `x.` followed by ctrl+space?